# Learning a classifier to compute distance between points for clustering

Tags: classification, clustering

I have dataset of items and want to cluster them. However, I don't have a predefined distance function. Does it make sense to learn a classifier that can predict the similarity between any two items?

Dataset:
A, B, C, ...

Unknown distance function: dfn(X, Y) => [0.0, 1.0]

Training dataset for classifier (let us say we only train for similar(1.0) or not(0.0))
A, B => 1.0
A, C => 0.0
A, D => 1.0
...

After this, during the clustering operation, when I need a distance score for any two items x and y. Can I use classify(x, y) as the distance function?

Answer (score 1):

A classifier is usually not well designed to produce a meaningful *distance*.
The value returned is a *confidence* but the reason for low confidence doesn't necessarily mean the objects are similar.

Instead, have a look at **distance learning** literature. People have spend effort into coming up with clever ways of learning distances from training data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to point me to a good starting point (A gentle introduction or Wikipedia article etc?).

Comment: I'm not using distance learning myself.

Comment: Other names for distance learning are: **metric learning** and **similarity learning** Both names in google will give you some of the relevant literature